# Show derivative function is bounded to prove uniform continuity

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity, uniform-continuity

I've been trying to solve this question:

> Let $f(x) = \frac {x}{x+sin x}$, prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $(0,\infty)$

I've been trying to prove that $f'$ is bounded in $(0,\infty)$, but reached:

$f'(x)= \frac {sin x - xcosx}{(x+sin x)^2}$

I'm not sure how to go on from here to show that $f'$ is truly bounded. Would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: By blocked, do you mean bounded?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes, thank you. I'm studying in Hebrew, and some terms are missed. I'll edit the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

For big enough $x$, say $x > A$, we have that $|f'(x)|$ is bounded. Since $f$ has a limit at $0$, we can say that it is a restriction of a continuous function  defined on $[0, \infty)$. In particular, $f$ is the restriction of a continous function defined in the compact set $[0, A]$, therefore it's uniformly continuous there and has a bounded derivative at $(A, \infty)$, so it is also uniformly continuous there. Since it is also continuous at $A$ you can argument a bit to show that the original $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Can you please explain to me a bit better how is $f$ uniformly continuous in $(0,A]$?
I can agree that $f'$ is bounded in $(A,\infty)$

Comment: I'm using two results: 1) continuous functions of compact sets are uniformly continuous; 2) a restriction of a uniformly continuous function is also uniformly continuous.

In the following, what I'll call $f$ is actually the restriction of $f$ to $(0, A]$. Let's call $F$ the extension of $f$ to the compact set $[0, A]$, which is obtained by setting $F(0)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$. Then $F$ is continuous on a compact set, and therefore uniformly continuous, by 1). It follows by 2) that $f$, the restriction of $F$ to (0, A], is uniformly continuous.